# Is there a better way to write this URL Manipulation in Python?

Tags: python, url, parsing

I'm curious if there's a simpler way to remove a particular parameter from a url. What I came up with is the following. This seems a bit verbose. Libraries to use or a more pythonic version appreciated.

```
parsed = urlparse(url)
if parsed.query != "":
    params = dict([s.split("=") for s in parsed.query.split("&")])
    if params.get("page"):
        del params["page"]
    url = urlunparse((parsed.scheme,
                      None,
                      parsed.path,
                      None,
                      urlencode(params.items()),
                      parsed.fragment,))
    parsed = urlparse(url)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've created a small helper class to represent a url in a structured way:

```
import cgi, urllib, urlparse

class Url(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        """Construct from a string."""
        self.scheme, self.netloc, self.path, self.params, self.query, self.fragment = urlparse.urlparse(url)
        self.args = dict(cgi.parse_qsl(self.query))

    def __str__(self):
        """Turn back into a URL."""
        self.query = urllib.urlencode(self.args)
        return urlparse.urlunparse((self.scheme, self.netloc, self.path, self.params, self.query, self.fragment))
```

Then you can do:

```
u = Url(url)
del u.args['page']
url = str(u)
```

More about this: [Web development peeve](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201004/web_development_peeve.html).

Comment: A reasonable compromise. Far more useful than urlparse I would say ;)

Comment: I've made some [modifications to this class](http://twigstechtips.blogspot.com/2011/02/python-simple-query-string-manipulation.html), making it a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 11):

Use [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) to crack the query string. You can filter this in one go:

```
params = [(k,v) for (k,v) in parse_qsl(parsed.query) if k != 'page']
```

Comment: The url manipulation here seems tortured even with your minor change.

Comment: @dnolen: I agree. Python's baked-in libraries aren't particularly good for simple URI manipulation. (Did you downvote me? If so, it hardly seems reasonable to downvote someone because of limitations in the language or its libraries.)

Comment: I downvoted because your answer didn't attempt to address the actual problem, and some people seemed to think otherwise. In any case at 14.3k karma it hardly affects you.

Comment: The rep isn't the issue here; what irks me is that you think I wasn't trying to help solve your problem. The title question was: "Is there a better way to write this URL Manipulation in Python?" My answer offers precisely that.

Comment: Is it really necessary to say `[(k,v) for (k,v) ...]` instead of, say, `[x for x ...]`?

Comment: @bvukelic: No, but then you'd have to write `if x[0] …`, which isn't as clear.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Ah yes, I overlooked that bit.