# how to output an HTML GET variable in python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, get

there's lots of information on retrieving GET variables from a python script. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to send GET variables from a python script to an HTML page. So I'm just wondering if there's a simple way to do this.

I'm using Google App Engine webapp to develop my site. Thanks for your support!

Comment: What do you mean send GET variables to HTML? Get variables can be set in url, after "?" character and divided by "&" character: `<a href="/somewhere/?var1=value1&var2=value2>`. When user clicks on that link server will get two GET variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to write this URL Manipulation in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873438/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-url-manipulation-in-python)

Comment: @Quentin - that looks pretty complicated...I was looking for a simple solution that I overlooked. thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append the get parameters to the url: `request.html?param1=value1&param2=value2`.
Now you could just create your string with some python variables which would hold the param names and values.

**Edit**: better use python's url lib:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'param1': 'value1', 'param2': 'value2', 'value3': 'param3'})
url = "example.com?%s" % params
```

Comment: Ok, I added an example with python's urllib. I think this should work.