# Python modify the path of url without hacky string interpolation

Tags: python

How to use `urllib.parse` in python to modify the path of URI? I know I can use substring and index but I am wondering what is the right way to accomplish this.

Convert this:

https://foo.blob.bar.storage.azure.net/container/blobname?sv=2015-04-05&ss=123&srt=abc&sp=efg&se=2022&sig=wsx

To this:

https://foo.blob.bar.storage.azure.net/container?sv=2015-04-05&ss=123&srt=abc&sp=efg&se=2022&sig=wsx

Comment: Python's `string.replace()` won't do?

Comment: can we parse the uri and mofiy the path and rebuild the uri?

Comment: @Aziz not sure how string.replace could be used without assuming last backslash doesn't happen in the query part of uri as well

Comment: I assumed that `/blobname` would be the part to remove. I've posted an answer with details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to write this URL Manipulation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873438/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-url-manipulation-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove `/blobname` from the URL, you can simply use:

```
url = 'https://foo.blob.bar.storage.azure.net/container/blobname?sv=2015-04-05&ss=123&srt=abc&sp=efg&se=2022&sig=wsx'
new_url = url.replace('/blobname', '')
```

However, if you really want to parse the URL and reconstruct it (let's say you want to go up one directory in the URL path), you can do this:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
from pathlib import Path

url = 'https://foo.blob.bar.storage.azure.net/container/blobname?sv=2015-04-05&ss=123&srt=abc&sp=efg&se=2022&sig=wsx'

u = urlparse(url)
url_parts = list(u)   # Need to convert to list to update the path item
url_parts[2] = str(Path(u.path).parent)   # Using Path lib to go to the parent path
new_url = urlunparse(url_parts)  # create a new URL
```